# How to install several hard-drives to Tyan S7025 motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid, sata, sas

First of all, the disclaimer: I do not know much about computers.

CONTEXT

In February 2010 I purchased a workstation with a Tyan S7025 motherboard. This motherboard has 6 SATA ports (SATA0 to SATA5) and 2 miniSAS ports (J18/J19).

The workstation came with 3 hard-drives (2 MBA3300RC and 1 WD2002FYPS), all connected to J18. In turn, the DVDRW was connected to SATA0. Power-wise, the 3 HD were connected to the power source sharing the same cable, whereas the DVDRW was connected through its own cable (identical to the other one).

QUESTION

Now I would like to add three more drives. One WD2002FYPS (identical to the one already installed) and 2 MZ-7PD256BW (SSD).

The question is how to connect the 6 drives to the motherboard and the power supply?

Should I, for instance, connect 3 drives to J18 and 3 to J19? Which ones? Or is this irrelevant? Should I use the SATA ports instead? But, if so, where I should plug the DVDRW?

Power-wise, should I buy a new cable and connect, for instance, the two SSD together with the DVDRW and the other 4 HD together?

NOTE1: All sockets in the power source are occupied.

NOTE2: It may help to know what I want to do with the drives. The 2 MZ-7PD256BW will be in some kind of RAID0 (either via the RAID controller, LVM or ZFs, that is yet to be determined) and will be used to store output from calculations (running 24/24 and 365/365). The 2 MBA3300RC will also be RAID0 (real or virtual) and will be used for fast backup via rsync every 24 hours. The 2 WD2002FYPS will in RAID1 (also real or virtual) and will be used for permanent backups.

Best regards,

Miro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some background.

SAS and SATA are both modern interfaces. [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) is mostly used to connect harddrives or optical media in consumer space.

[SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI) is a similar standard which replaced the old paralel SCSI interface in workstations and servers. SAS is more complex, more robust, and often more expensive.

A direct SAS connection can use SATA drives (albeit with reduced functionality. E.g. you loose the nice graceful handling which you get when a SAS drive on a SAS bus fails).

Last background: The connectors for SAS and SATA are nearly identical. SAS drives have a single connector feeding both power and signals. SATA has two cables, one for power, one for data/signals. And SATA has a small gap between these two.

[image: SAS and SATA connector]

As a result you can simply plug a SATA drive on a SAS connector and it will work.

---

Now your situation:

You have [a motherboard](http://www.tyan.com/product_SKU_spec.aspx?ProductType=MB&pid=641&SKU=600000040) which accepts both SAS and SATA drives.

You have a trio of drives. Two (`MBA3300RC`) are 15k RPM 3½ inch **SAS** drives. One (the Western Digital WD2002FYPS) is a 2TB RE4GP 64 MB 7200 RPM **SATA** Enterprise hard drive

- You need to connect the SAS drives to the SAS bus for them to work.
- You can connected the third drive to either one of the free SATA connectors or to the SAS connector, and it would work just as well in both cases. In your case the person building the system selected the SAS connector.

> I would like to add three more drives.
>   One WD2002FYPS (identical to the one already installed) and 2 MZ-7PD256BW (SSD).

Your two mini SAS connectors allow for up to 8 (two sets of four) drives. So you could connect all of them to the SAS connector. However if you are going to heavily use the SSD then it might<sup>*</sup> benefit from TRIM.

You use TRIM you need to connect the SSDs to one of the SATA connectors.

As for the other drive: Either SAS and SATA would works, and having both drives on the SAS bus feels more *natural* to me. However that is just a feeling, possibly born out of a desire for symmetry and the resulting 'logic' when I next look to it.

> Power-wise, should I buy a new cable and connect, for instance, the two SSDs together with the DVD-RW and the other 4 HDD together?

That would work. Except for the connector there is no difference in the power feeds to either drives, SSDs or the DVD. THus it mostly comes down to 1) Which cables do I already own, and 2) How can I mount the cables in the case without them getting in the way of cooling fans.

> NOTE1: All sockets in the power source are occupied.

So you need to buy new cables anyway. LOok at the inside of the server, **after** reading my answer on NOTE2.

> NOTE2: It may help to know what I want to do with the drives. 
>   The 2 MZ-7PD256BW will be in some kind of RAID0 (either via the RAID controller,
>   LVM or ZFS, that is yet to be determined) and will be used to store output from
>   calculations (running 24/24 and 365/365).
>
> The 2 MBA3300RC will also be RAID0 (real or virtual) and will be used for fast
>   backup via rsync every 24 hours.
>
> The 2 WD2002FYPS will in RAID1 (also real or virtual) and will be used for 
>   permanent backups.

Hold it. Backups on the same server? Please reconsider that.

If the server is stolen, if there is a fire, if there is a power surge or anything else which takes out your computer and you have the backups in the same place then you have a problem.  Please consider off-site and preferably off-line backups.

In other words: You want to mount the permanent backup drive(s) in another place.

---

<sup>*</sup>: Might. Having TRIM turned on is a good thing, but you might not notice any difference if you just use the drive lightly for a few years. In my case I got a Intel G2 80GB drive without trim on a SAS cable and it is still extremely fast after 6 years of normal desktop usage. If you are going to write 50 TB per day for a few years to it then you really want TRIM or a drive which optimizes itself when idle.

Comment: OK, thank you for your clear explanation. For the connection to the motherboard, you said "connect the SSDs to one of the SATA connectors", my question is: should I connect both to the same port or each one to one port (I have 5 available, apart from the one used by the DVDRW)? Then the 2 SAS will go in one miniSAS port but, again, both in the same port or each one in one port? The other two SATA drives, is it better for them to go in the other miniSAS port or should I also use the available SATA connectors for those ones?

Comment: Let me clarify that. One SSD per SATA port. This is normal for SATA. So to connect both the DVD and both SSDs you would use a total of three SATA ports.  As for the two big SATA HDDs, either way will work. PErsonally I would connect them to the SAS controller because I tend to trust SAS over SATA, but I got no hard facts to back that up.

Comment: OK, now it is totally clear. Thanks a million! Just one extra question: would it make any difference if I connect the two SAS to J18 and the two SATA to J19 or is it the same if I attach all four drives to the same port?

Comment: According to the manual the board has one LSI SAS1068 which is connected to both Mini-SAS (4-in-1) connectors. Thus it does not matter.